# Setup Magento to write on multiple mysql masters

Tags: mysql, performance, magento, replication, cluster-computing

I'm completely newbie in mysql cluster. I was trying long ours to find if, when I setup magento with mysql cluster, it will write to one of the nodes or always to one node?

My second question is, when I setup mysql replication: one master and one slave, and master server die, will magento start to write on slave, or my app stop working?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

1)

Magento supports by default: 1 master and multiple read slaves.
For specific modules you can define different read/write custom connections. So, with this setup you could write data to multiple mysql master servers.

*Notice: None of the large Magento hosting partners/providers (nbs, nexcess, peer1, etc) managed to have a working solution with multiple db masters.*

2) No. there is no auto switch to slave.

Comment: I need solution that has not any single point of failure. Maybe there is another way to find db-server-crash and switch in short time to another server?

Comment: You can contact some Magento Industry Partners (peer1, nbs, nexcess) as a customer (just say you are a huge one, so they actually follow your request as an important lead) and ask how they cover this aspect... Might want to try with haproxy